# Avoiding full table scans

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have an issue with the following query

```
UPDATE P 
set    P.price =  (select top 1 PV.price 
                   from  @port_values PV      
                   where PV.pv_id < P.pv_id 
                   and   PV.price is not NULL 
                   and   PV.id    = P.id 
                   order by  PV.pv_id desc) 
FROM   @port_values P 
WHERE  P.price is NULL
```

What it is doing is a look back through history to find any previously pervious price value and applying to the places where there is a NULL price. `pv_id` is in date order and indexed. It was previously ordering by date, but no change in performance.

It was working with a reasonable performance, however the database it getting larger and this line of code is effectively hanging the query. For smaller sets of data it is OK, but in the case where @port_values has about 400k rows. It clearly is doing an iterative table scans and not efficient at all. I have tried putting indexes on the columns with any performance.

What would be the most efficient way structure a query like this?

Comment: use temp table. You will be able to create index on temp table

Comment: it is a table variable and is indexed. Could do it as a temp table but not sure it would change anything.

Comment: MAybe clustered index would be helpful?

Comment: please post the schema and show what are the available indexes

Comment: @BenWatson What indexes did you create on that table variable? That is quite significant. Also note that table variables are still a different 'beast' compared to temporary tables. Statistics is one thing that table variables do not have and cardinality estimations are usually off (except on recompiles). Read more here: [What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/65699)

Answer (score 0):

Since your environment is not available, we can't give exact solution. But try below and let me know if there is any impact on performance

**Method 1:**

```
UPDATE P SET  P.price = PV.price
FROM @port_values P
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, price FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PV.id ORDER BY PV.pv_id ASC) AS SNO
    ,PV.id
    ,PV.price
    FROM @port_values PV
    WHERE PV.price is not NULL 
    )AS A
    WHERE SNO= 1
)PV ON P.id = PV.ID
WHERE P.price is NULL
```

Method 2:

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, price DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT id, price FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PV.id ORDER BY PV.pv_id ASC) AS SNO
,PV.id
,PV.price
FROM @port_values PV
WHERE PV.price is not NULL 
)AS A
WHERE SNO= 1


UPDATE P SET  P.price = PV.price
FROM @port_values P 
INNER JOIN #TAB PV ON P.id = PV.ID
WHERE P.price is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this non-standard sql performs better,

```
UPDATE P 
set    P.price =  s.price
FROM   @port_values P
    Outer apply(
        select top 1 PV.price
        from @port_values PV 
        where PV.pv_id < P.pv_id
        and PV.price is not NULL 
        and PV.id = P.id 
        and P.price is null
        order by  PV.pv_id desc ) s
WHERE  P.price is NULL
```

Comment: What is non-standard about this?  I mean, `top` is not standard, but that is in the OP's original query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `outer apply`

Answer (score 0):

Use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select p.*,
             lag(p.price) over (partition by p.pv_id order by p.id) as prev_price
      from @port_values p
      where p.price is not null
     )
update toupdate
    set price = prev_price;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(pv_id, id, price)`.  These are allowed on table variables in more recent versions of SQL Server.  In older versions, use a temporary table so you can add the indexes.